# How to convert libgdx int keycode to char?

Tags: java, libgdx

How do I convert the `libgdx` keycode to the actual character pressed on the keyboard? When I try to implicitly convert to a character it is totally wrong.

Comment: Use the toString(int keycode) method provided by the Keys class.

Answer (score 1):

There is a predefined table in libGDX in: `Input.Keys` for ex. `Input.Keys.A`.
To get a `String`(not `char`, but you can easily convert this) use a `toString(int keycode)` 
function - check it out in `Input.Keys`.
I hope it helps!
Cheers,
staticcasty